# Microsoft Word inserts `É` character when typing `?`

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard, language, input

Currently when I attempt to enter a question mark in any application it works fine and I get the following symbol: ?

But when I hit the same input inside Microsoft Word I get the following symbol: É

What is causing this? In the Options → Language menu option, English (Canada) is selected, and my system keyboard is set to English (Canada) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I remembered my old friend had exactly same problem before - he said that there's likely originated from shortcut key to switch keyboard layout which may have inadvertently changed input language.

Here are some steps you need to try:

1. Navigate to Control Panel => Region and Language => Keyboards and Languages => click Change keyboards button.
2. "Text Services and Input Languages" dialog box will show up, open "Advanced Key Settings" which shows like below (i.e. your keyboard setting may contain English & French instead of listed languages in sample image).

[image: Advanced Key Settings]

3. There you can found "Left Alt + Shift" to change between input languages, try to use it on Word document by pressing `Left Alt` + `Shift` + slash (/) character sequence repeatedly until question mark appears properly.
4. If you want getting rid of unpleasant shortcut key, turn it off by using "Change Key Sequence" and uncheck "Enable Key Sequence" or set to "Not Assigned" (see images below).

[image: Change Key Sequence: Between Input Languages]

[image: Change Key Sequence: Single Language]

Additional references:

[Instead of getting a question mark, I get É. How do I changed it?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/instead-of-getting-a-question-mark-i-get-%C3%A9/e5c6e596-4647-4ad2-a4f9-0ef785324e81)

[Question mark is not available on the question mark/oblique key. Only a red French "E" is available. Can I change this to make the question mark available? If so, how?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/question-mark-is-not-available-on-the-question/465c0ffa-ef75-4dd7-adc2-adc3817426aa)